# How to make a phone call without saving the number?

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm using the following code to make a call in Android but I would like to **hide the number being called, and not save it in the call log**. Is it possible?

```
String num="xxx-xxx-xxx"; 
String number = "tel:" + num.trim();
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: If you are using the call intent, I'm afraid it's not up to you to decide whether the number will be saved.

Comment: so you want to call a number, but you don't want your user to know what number is being called?

Comment: you realize it's bound to appear on the detailed bill even if you could hide it from the log? Also, I assume this is a very specific need, because I would not like an app to call some number without telling me who I am calling.

Comment: @njzk2 example: 
I want to call a person, I save the phone number inside the app and call it. If someone else use my smartphone, he shouldn't find the number of this person.

Comment: encrypt and lock your smartphone. Where do you store the number anyway?

Comment: They are not the same thing. in a database.